# Set conditions for draggable objects when dropped - Jquery - UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

Let's say we have multiple draggable elements in one page and multiple droppable targets. Each draggable element has only one droppable target. My question is: how to test if the right element is being dropped on it's right target.
Here is an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D25Rt/

this is the code from the example:

```
$("#draggable-red, #draggable-blue, #draggable-green").draggable({ revert: "invalid", containment: "#content"});

$("#droppable-red").droppable({
    accept: "#draggable-red",
    activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight").find("p").html("Touch down!");
    }
});

$("#droppable-blue").droppable({
    accept: "#draggable-blue",
    activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight").find("p").html("Touch down!");
    }
});

$("#droppable-green").droppable({
    accept: "#draggable-green",
    activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight").find("p").html("Touch down!");
    }
});
```

To be more specific, regarding the previous example, if I drag the blue ball over the red box, when I release the blue ball I want to display an alert( something like "Wrong box..."). I'm new to jQuery UI, can someone give me some hints on how and where should i do that? in the **accept** option or in the **drop** option ?

Comment: You'll need to make use of the `stop` method of `draggable`. Read more here: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop

Answer (score 1):

Drop event is trigerred  [only when accepted draggable is dropped on droppable](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop), so I would first reconsider using accept option - you can pass function that returns true/false as argument.

But! Function passed to accept is called for all draggable elements on page, so creating something like:

```
    accept: function(){
        if($(".ui-draggable-dragging").is("#draggable-red"))
            return true;
        else
            alert("I only accept red ball!");
    },
```

[Causes multiple alerts even if you just try to move other draggable ball.](http://jsfiddle.net/QB7fa/)

Something like that should be okay:

```
drop: function(event, ui) {
    if(ui.draggable.is("#draggable-red")){
        $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight").find("p").html("Touch down!");
    }
    else{
        alert("I accept only red balls!");
        ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',true);
    }
}
```

But it must accept all elements, so it breaks your highlight.

JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bFj68/1/

Hope it helps somehow.